# Facebook marketing API get expectedSize of CustomAudience Error: Tried accessing nonexisting field (expectedSize) on node type (CustomAudience)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I have a piece of code that should fetch the size of a custom audience using the Facebook Marketing API. For some reason I can reach almost all fields on the CustomAudience object but when I try to read expectedSize it returns this error.

```
(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (expectedSize) on node type (CustomAudience)
```

Here is my code

```
public function getAudienceSize($id) {
    $customAudience = new CustomAudience($id);
    $fields = ['name', 'id', 'expectedSize'];
    $customAudience->getSelf($fields);
    $data = $customAudience->getData();
    dd($data);
}
```

Comment: And where exactly did you find this field documented? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience doesn’t mention it at all.

Comment: @04FS you were correct! It was called approximate_count

Answer (score 0):

The name of the field is

```
approximate_count
```

and not

```
expectedSize
```